# how can i use library Spotipy to search a uri track when i have the title, and the year of release

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

I have a dataset structured with title of a track used in a film, title of the film, year of the film. I need to find the uri of the track on spotify using python. I need to search every tracks by the title  and the year of the film

this is an example of what i try

```
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials
import json

credentials = json.load(open('autorizzazione.json'))
client_id = credentials['client_id']
client_secret = credentials['client_secret']

client_credentials_manager =
SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id=client_id,client_secret=client_secret)
sp = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=client_credentials_manager)

listasong =pd.read_csv("dataset.csv")

research = sp.search([listasong["track"][0],listasong["year"][0]]  , limit=1, offset=0, type=["track, year"] , market=None)    ##track is the name of the column that contain the title of the song
```

this gave me error because it say my research is poorly. In a second moment i need to switch year with title_film to search by title of the song, and title of the album, because often the album or the compilation on spotify have the name of the film in it.

Comment: Can you shows a couple of example of `[listasong["track"][0],listasong["year"][0]]`?

Answer (score 0):

The `q` of `search(q, limit=10, offset=0, type='track', market=None)` should be one string. Also, `year` is not a type.
Bellow is my rewritten and fixed code:

```
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials
import pandas as pd
import json

credentials = json.load(open('autorizzazione.json'))
client_id = credentials['client_id']
client_secret = credentials['client_secret']

auth_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret)
sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=auth_manager)

listasong = pd.read_csv("dataset.csv")

q = f"track:\"{listasong['track'][0]}\" year:{listasong['year'][0]}"
research = sp.search(q=q, limit=1, offset=0, type="track", market=None)
```